# Create a custom API to use Microsoft Graph to send emails

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, email, microsoft-graph-api, multi-tenant

I want to develop a custom ASP.NET Web API which can be used to send out emails as a user using the Microsoft Graph API. I think this will be a Multi-tenant application. Below are few ideas I have and some questions:

1. I have a working ASP.NET MVC web application where different users can login using their unique credentials provided by us.
2. I have an "Email Setup" section in my web app. Every user will navigate to this section one-time and be redirected to the "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={{client_id}}&response_type=code&redirect_uri={{redirect_uri}}&response_mode=query&scope=offline_access%20user.read%20mail.read&state=12345"
3. On the consent screen user will sign in using their Microsoft Office 365 credentials and provide consent to my app.
4. On providing consent, user will be redirected back to my web app and I will get Access token for the code returned and store the access token in a SQL database.
5. User navigates to a page to send email, fills in the To, Subject, Body, Attachments etc. and clicks on the "Send" button.
6. On send button, my ASP.NET web app will call our custom Web API to send the email. The API will have an endpoint that knows the user and will get appropriate access token from the SQL database to send email on that user's behalf.

Questions:

1. Do I need to register an Azure App with type "Multi-tenant" since I want to support users from different tenants?
2. What kind of scopes/permissions will be required in order to "Send Email" as the user?
3. Do I need Delegated/Application permissions on the Azure side?
4. How can I ensure that the email that is sent, also gets saved to that user's "Sent Items" folder on Outlook?

Comment: Hi, if the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [sending email graph api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), we can see it provides the `Application` api permission, that means you can create an azure ad application and assign the `Mail.Send` permission to this api and using [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) to generate access token to call this api, so it's not necessary to creating a multi-tenant azure ad application via this way.

And certainly, if you insist on auth code flow to generate access token to using delegate permission to call the api, you should creating a multi-tenant application so that users from different tenant can generate access token through this azure ad application.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Do you think I can use this approach to send about 100000 bulk emails daily? My idea is to queue the emails in a SQL database when user hits send on the Web App and then process the emails from SQL database using a background processor.

Comment: @NaupadDoshi Hi, thanks for your reply, but I'm really not able to give you an exactly answer on it as I never tried it. What I can say is that there's no count limitation mentioned in the document so I think you can try it first, and if there's some incident took place, you can then raise another question here with your code snippet, your configuration and exception or error message.